# Start using SAT Solvers

Tags: complexity-theory, logic

What i actually want to do is to turn a math problem ,i have to solve,to a Boolean Satisfiability problem and solve it using a SAT Solver.
I wonder if someone knows any manual,guide or anything that will help me to make my problem solve using a SAT Solver.From what i found so far,SAT Solver's do not have any good documentations..

Comment: What's the math problem you want to solve?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question?

Comment: See Chapter 2 of the SAT handbook, or the other references in http://jsat.ewi.tudelft.nl/addendum/Bjork_encoding.pdf